# How to differentiate $\left(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^5$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can I differentiate this expression
$$\left(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right)^5$$
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: There are many ways to differentiate the given expression. What we are looking for is your effort. If you are stuck somewhere, we can help.

Comment: How about chain rule?

Comment: Using calculus differentiation

Comment: You can try to apply the chain rule. You can find it in almost every textbook.

Comment: $5 = 2 \times \frac{5}{2}$ so you can seperate the equation expression: $$\bigg(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)^5 \to \bigg(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)^{2 \times 2\frac{1}{2} = \bigg(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)^4 \times \sqrt {x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Comment: $$\bigg(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)^5 \to \bigg(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)^{2 \times 2\frac{1}{2}} = \bigg(x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)^4 \times \sqrt {x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2}}

Comment: ???? What ???? bruh

Comment: @GeorgeN.Missailidis You need another set of \$\$ after the math text.

Answer (score 3):

Chain rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
use $g(x)=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$ and $f(x)=x^5$.

Power rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}\qquad\text{where $n\in\Bbb Z/\{0\}$}$$
note, $\frac{1}{x^2}=x^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the Chain Rule:$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$

where $f(x)=x^5$ and $g(x)=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$. $$\\$$

For  $f'(g(x))$ we get:

$$f'(x)= 5(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})^4.$$

For $g'(x)$ we can separate the expression:

$$\frac{d}{dx} (x^2) + \frac{d}{dx} (\frac{1}{x^2})$$

$\frac{d}{dx} (x^2) = 2x$ and $\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{1}{x^2}) = \frac{-2}{x^3}$.

So, For $g'(x)$ we get:

$$2x-\frac{2}{x^3}.$$

Thus, we get  $f'(g(x))g'(x)$ as:

$$(5(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2})^4)(2x-\frac{2}{x^3}).$$